# Why do I get "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type"?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I do not understand why I get this error. I tried google but i think that my code seems right...
In main I have this:

```
Database *database;
database = (Database *)malloc(db_sizeOfStruct());

database->key = "word";
```

And in my module file I have this:

```
typedef struct database {
     char key;
     char value;
     struct database *next;
} Database;

int db_sizeOfStruct() {
    return sizeof(struct database);
}
```

The compiler gives "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type", why? I am trying to understand pointers, it's propably something about them I suppose...

Comment: Because you are dereferencing a pointer to incomplete type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the code in `main()` doesn't have access to the declaration of the `struct`, you can't use it like you do.

Either make the declaration public (in the `module.h`) or make the allocation inside the module.

Also you can't allocate a string (`char *`) to a single `char`, but that's a different error message.

Also, [please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: I see! I accidently used the -> allocation for testing purposes, I will make a set function for that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `key`, which is a char. You are trying to assign a pointer to char to a char.

Comment: That's not the reason for the error message quoted by the OP.

Comment: Ah! Now I see. The char * -> char error was so obvious that I thought it was the cause for the error message. Anyway, a slightly more detailed comment would be better. Just a "that's not the answer" or "that's not the reason" isn't quite helpful.

Comment: There are correct answers around. If felt it wasn't necessary to just repeat those. And it's also always a good idea to read and understand the error message. In this case it was mentioning the word "dereference" which should norrow down the issue quiet well.

Answer (score 1):

Since this compiles pefectly:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct database {
    char key;
    char value;
    struct database *next;
} Database;

int db_sizeOfStruct() {
    return sizeof(struct database);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Database *database;
    database = (Database *)malloc(db_sizeOfStruct());

    database->key = 'w';//"word";

    return 0;
}
```

I assume you have this in a separate file that is unknown to main:

```
typedef struct database {
    char key;
    char value;
    struct database *next;
} Database;

int db_sizeOfStruct() {
    return sizeof(struct database);
}
```

Then this main have no idea what `Database` is:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Database *database;
    database = (Database *)malloc(db_sizeOfStruct());

    database->key = 'w';//"word";

    return 0;
}
```

Also, see the assigning of `"word"` to a `char`, which obviously cannot be on purpose.

Comment: You are right in that there is two separate files. The file containing the struct also has an header file where the typedef is defined as "typedef struct database Database;". I think that the type Database would be known in main then?

Answer (score 0):

`Key` is of type char but `"word"` is a string literal what means it has type `char *`

Comment: I don't know either. I've upped it.

Comment: Because it's not the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure definition should look like:

```
typedef struct database {
     char *key;
     char value;
     struct database *next;
} Database;
```

Look at

```
char *key;
```

Your previous member was:

```
char key;
```

Just a single character that cannot hold a pointer to the "word" string.

Anyway, I have never seen using a function to return a size of some type.

`malloc(sizeof(struct database));`

is ugly?

Comment: That's not the reason for the error message quoted by the OP.